# How to split Toolbar into two rows for certain screen in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I want to split HeaderToolbar into two rows when my screen width is less then 570px.

```
<headerToolbar>
<Toolbar id="dsdfgfanfgjd">
    <FormattedText class="customPanelHeader" htmlText="customHtml"></FormattedText>
    <ToolbarSpacer></ToolbarSpacer>
        <Input id="searchFilter" class="searchFilterInput"  placeholder="filter value" value="{/searchFilter}" width="12em" liveChange=".onChangedSearchFilter" valueLiveUpdate="true"/>
        <core:Icon class="searchFilterIcon" size="1.75em" src="sap-icon://search" tooltip="search"/>
</Toolbar>
```

[![Toolbar 
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaClT.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaClT.png)

How i can manange it for small screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the responsive side of Toolbar,use HBOX. it will automatically align them when screen size change. Please test if it fixes your problem.

```
<Toolbar height='auto'>
                <content>
                    <HBox width='100%' wrap='Wrap'>
                        <items>
                            <Text text='text0' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text1' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text2' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text3' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text4' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text5' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text6' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text7' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text8' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text9' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text10' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text11' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text12' width='3rem' />
                            <ToolbarSpacer></ToolbarSpacer>
                            <Input id="searchFilter" class="searchFilterInput"
                                placeholder="filter value" value="{/searchFilter}" width="100%"
                                liveChange=".onChangedSearchFilter" valueLiveUpdate="true" />
                            <core:Icon class="searchFilterIcon" size="1.75rem"
                                src="sap-icon://search" tooltip="search" />
                        </items>
                    </HBox>
                </content>
            </Toolbar>
```

Please note the height of Toolbar is set to 'auto' to adjust according to no. of rows created when items are re-aligned. Also, the width is HBOX is set to '100%' to occupy entire space available on screen.

Comment: and how to move seach filter at right side? on 2nd line I've only searchfilter. and i want to put it on right side.